# Unknown host error in browser on mobile network

Tags: internet

I have a rooted HTC One X running a custom ROM. I use a firewall and Xprivacy for managing permissions. When on my Vodafone India 3G network, I can't open any site other than Google using the default browser because it reports a DNS error saying unknown host. All other apps work fine regardless of 3G or Wi-Fi. I've white listed the browser in Xprivacy and the firewall so it's not due to permissions being denied. 
It works fine on Wi-Fi. Anything else I should check?

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: The built in android browser, nothing special.

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting a file named 'hosts' from /system/etc. And reboot :)

Comment: Copy it somewhere as a backup first is always good advice! Just in case something goes horribly wrong!

Comment: Backup is not required in this case. On boot the hosts file is re-written with localhost info on it. Create a backup if it pleases you.

Comment: Yeah I know how it works, but you know yourself: In theory it does all that, in reality this is a custom ROM and if something **can** go wrong, it probably **will**!

Comment: Good point there.

Comment: Renaming/moving the file instead of deleting it will also help if you accidentally do it to the wrong file. It's not unheard of.

Comment: How is that supposed to work? I use ad away and my hosts file has just ad servers in it. Like I said, I only see the problem on mobile network, over WiFi everything works fine.